# how many constraint we applied on one column in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I am practicing database constraints and I have a question. 
How many constraints can we apply on one column in a table?
Wrote now I am able to use two constraints on one column but not able to use the third constraint.
So could you tell me how many constraints can we apply on one column in a table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an unlimited number of constraint on one column according to [this site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm)

Show us an example of your code / query so we can help you